# MySQLdb installed from pypm doesn't work with 32-bit python on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, mysql-python, pypm

Before proceeding further, here are some details of my Mac and the installed python (ActivePython) and wxpython versions:

***Mac version: 10.6.6
Python version: 2.7.1 (ActiveState Python)
wxPython version: wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-py2.7***

Here is a small code that I wrote to test:

```
#! /usr/bin/env arch -i386 /usr/local/bin/python

import time
import random
import re
import wx
from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin
import serial
import itertools
import datetime
import sys
import os
import MySQLdb

print "Hello World"
```

Here is the error that I got from running it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sar.pyw", line 13, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/Users/ven/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ven/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Users/ven/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/ven/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/_mysql.so
```

As you can see I am using 32-bit python in the shebang line because I need to work with [wxpython](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/wxpython/) which runs only on 32-bit. Now, the only package that has problem with the 32-bit python is the [MySQLdb](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/mysql-python/) which has been installed using:

```
pypm install mysql-python
```

If I just removed the line

```
import MySQLdb
```

from the above piece of code, it runs perfectly and prints "Hello World".

If I removed "arch -i386" from the shebang line, the wxpython package doesn't work. I want to use both wxpython and MySQLdb at the same time. How do I do it?

Comment: According to www.wxpython.org 64 bit version of wxpython are available for the Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Duplicate](http://community.activestate.com/node/6641) ;-)

This is a [known bug](http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=87704) -- the `mysql-python` package is built only for 64-bit at the moment.

> I want to use both wxpython and MySQLdb at the same time. How do I do it?

wxPython 2.8 doesn't support 64-bit (due to using Carbon), this is why the PyPM package is built for only 32-bit. You could try using wxPython 2.9.

**Workaround**: remove wxpython using pypm (`pypm uninstall wxpython`), and then install the development cocoa binary `wxPython2.9-osx-cocoa-py2.7` from [wxpython.org](http://wxpython.org/download.php#unstable).